# Can't resize lvm volume "lv_home is in use. e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting"

Tags: lvm, centos, resize2fs, e2fsck

I would like to shrink my logical volume for home directory, so that I can extend volume for root.

**`df -h`**

```
/dev/mapper/vg_mitoscomp-lv_root   50G   33G   15G  70% /
/dev/mapper/vg_mitoscomp-lv_home   53G  180M   51G   1% /home
```

**`lsblk`**

```
─sdc2                                                                      8:34   0 111.3G  0 part
  ├─vg_mitoscomp-lv_root (dm-0)                                           253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg_mitoscomp-lv_swap (dm-1)                                           253:1    0   7.6G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─vg_mitoscomp-lv_home (dm-2)                                           253:2    0  53.8G  0 lvm  /home
```

I can successfully unmount `/home`, but than I can't perform health check nor can I resize volume.

```
[root@MITOs-Comp ~]# e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg_mitoscomp-lv_home
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
/dev/mapper/vg_mitoscomp-lv_home is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

```
root@MITOs-Comp ~]# resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_mitoscomp-lv_home 10G
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/mapper/vg_mitoscomp-lv_home
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Comment: What is the output of running `fuser -m` on the mount point?

Comment: Empty output...

Comment: How about `grep lv_home /proc/mounts` and also `grep dm-2 /proc/mounts`?

Comment: Try `fuser -am` . The process that might be using the partition might be getting as some other user.

Comment: For people who get here through google, make sure you've stopped your NFS servers as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably doesn't tell you something you already know since you said the umount was successful.  But do a "more /etc/mtab".  This is the kernels mount file and the device shouldn't be mounted and not listed in the /etc/mtab file.

Comment: `/proc/mounts` is the kernel view; `/etc/mtab` may or may not be symlink'd there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing.

I had  the `/data (/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol07 )`  partion umounted, but block device could not be checked with `fsck.ext4`
with

```
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol07 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

error

`lsof` showed nothing.

Then I've made `#cat /etc/mtab`, and found that I had `/tmp` folder mounted to `/data/tmp` folder.

`umount /tmp`  solved the problem.